# bootstrap duallistbox move-up move-down

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have boostrap duallistbox and I would like to add the option of moving up or down the selected value.

Can someone please help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See **moveOnSelect** option referenced in the Settings section of this article:

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-jQuery-Dual-Select-Boxes-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Dual-Listbox/

"true: The options are automatically moved on selection. This setting is forced on touch devices."

"false: The selected options can be moved with a button."

Comment: I dont want to move on select... I want to be able to move UP or DOWN the selected values.

Answer (score 0):

You could add two buttons up and down. Add click handlers with two collections: one with all options in select and second with only selected options.

```
function MoveDown(dualListbox) {
        var selectedItems = dualListbox.elements.box2.find(':selected');

        for (var i = selectedItems.length - 1; i > -1; i--)
        {
            var allItems = dualListbox.elements.box2.find('option');
            var selectedItem = $(selectedItems[i]);
            var selectedIndex = selectedItem.index();
            selectedItem.insertAfter(allItems[selectedIndex + 1]);
        }
    }
```

pay attention that when you'll be writing MoveUp handler you should start from the beginning of all options collection and insert before previous option

Comment: Ho do we pass this "dualListbox" parameter to this MoveDown() method through button click??

Answer (score 0):

Here you Go for Up and down

```js
    function MoveDown(dualListbox) {
       var selectedItems = dualListbox.elements.box2.find(':selected');

       for (var i = selectedItems.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
           var allItems = dualListbox.elements.box2.find('option');
           var selectedItem = $(selectedItems[i]);
           var selectedIndex = selectedItem.index();
           selectedItem.insertAfter(allItems[selectedIndex + 1]);
       }
    }

    function MoveUp(dualListbox) {
       var selectedItems = dualListbox.elements.box2.find(':selected');

       for (var i = 0;i<=selectedItems.length;i++) {
           var allItems = dualListbox.elements.box2.find('option');
           var selectedItem = $(selectedItems[i]);
           var selectedIndex = selectedItem.index();
           selectedItem.insertBefore(allItems[selectedIndex - 1]);
       }
    }
```